# Split text based on a character in Excel (with functions or natively)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to split text by the first space. But since some rows don't either have multiple words with space between them or are empty, I get a #VALUE error for both the right and left column. How can I fix the errors? 
I use this for the text on the left of character:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

and this for the text on the right of character:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))
```

Here's a sample image: 
[image]

and here's [the sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w8Ur0Ir_Yf6SGP9eWZRxGK-h_yTf6D5z/view?usp=sharing) (just FYI):

Comment: Are you sure you're putting a comment to the right question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
B1=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)),A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))
C1=TRIM(MID(A1,1+LEN(B1),LEN(A1)))
```

[image]

[image]

To avoid zero value in column B for local Excel application if a cell in column A is empty use

```
B1=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)),A1&"",LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an answer to my question?

Comment: Formula in C1, returns BLANK ,, @Akina pls check the formula !!

Comment: @ImanGhavamabadi,, you want to split text by 1st space or anything else ??

Comment: Split by the first space. The first word in one column and the rest in another. 
Problem is, if there's only one word in a cell, it throws a #VALUE error. In addition, if it there isn't any text in a cell, it throws the same error.

Comment: @RajeshS For what record? I see correct results... screenshots from GoogleSheets added (do not pay attention to semicolons - it is national settings).

Comment: Thanks @Akin, it works now. But it's throwing a '0' in B column if the A cell is empty. 

Check out the [updated file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w8Ur0Ir_Yf6SGP9eWZRxGK-h_yTf6D5z/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @ImanGhavamabadi *it's throwing a '0' when in B column if the A cell is empty.* Yes, GoogleSheets acts correctly whereas local Excel autoformats empty string to number type obtaining zero. Check corrected formula.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a treat.

Comment: @Akina,,, I've tried both,, with `,` getting SPACE & with `;` getting error since using US English & KB .

Comment: @RajeshS Try insert a formula by code: `Range("B1").Formula="=IF(ISERROR(FIND("" "",A1)),A1&"""",LEFT(A1,FIND("" "",A1)-1))"`

Comment: @Akina,, it's never like to justify by any mean or method,, what I got,, since I tried the formula,,  I've written to you,, and neither delimiter symbol matters since text was suppose to separate by 1 st SPACE,,   comma and semicolons only matters to the Region !!

Comment: @RajeshS I have tested the formula in both Excel-2010 and GoogleSheets - and in both cases it gives correct results. So I cannot detect what's the problem.

Answer (score -1):

*Your used formula with little adjustments works properly:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `R34:`

  ```
  =IF(Q34="","",IF(LEN(TRIM(Q34))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Q34," ",""))+1=1,Q34,LEFT(Q34,FIND(" ",Q34)-1)))
  ```
- Second formula in cell `S34:`

  ```
  =IF(Q34="","",IF(LEN(TRIM(Q34))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Q34," ",""))+1=1,"",RIGHT(Q34,LEN(Q34)-FIND(" ",Q34))))
  ```

*You may adjust cell references as needed.*

Comment: Please write your concern that why this has been Down voted?